# Optimize pages for exact phrase typed in Google and show that phrase in the search box on site

Tags: seo, google-search-console

When I search a query on google `my query`, it shows a website on top, when I open that website (say `example.com`) it shows `my query` written in the search box of `example.com` and UR looks like `example.com/my-query` and even for some queries `example.com` says no results found (but still it comes on top for `my query`).

`example.com` can't do SEO for all the URLs like:

`example.com/my-query1`

`example.com/my-query2`

`example.com/my-query3`

How can I do the seo of my website like that? My website is like olx / craigslist and all pages are dynamic.

Comment: When you say the site can't do SEO for other URLs, does that mean you tried various URLs and they don't work?

Comment: It sounds like you found a site with their search results indexed.  You should read https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/ where Google's Matt Cutts explains why Google doesn't like to index search results and that Google penalizes sites that try to get their search pages indexed and ranked.   I wouldn't try to copy that site, it could get penalized and lose all its Google traffic.

Comment: A worth reading article, thank you. I haven't do the SEO for search result pages yet. I'm planning to save top 50 search queries to my website in sitemap.xml. Will that be a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is a display thing, not an SEO thing. I think what you are looking to do is:

1. get the referral url, then extract the search query params
2. create a slug out of the query params (My QuErY becomes my-query)
3. send the user to the default results page
4. use javascript to change the display URL to /my-query using the history object.

The URLs are only for display; they aren't persistent. So they won't have any impact on SEO. If you want, you can save the association between "search query" and "results page" in database. So the next time a user comes to the site using the same search query, you pull this results page from the database.

Comment: My site gets the search terms in the referrer only a few percent of the time now.    You used to be able to use the Google search query dynamically, but Google has taken that ability away almost entirely now.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, I believe that's because they started doing https. I still see keywords from yandex and yahoo, but occassionaly from google. The ones I see from google are most likely from the users who are not logged in to google at the time, or are using insecure url somehow.